# Take picture using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - How to get the image?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an Android 4+ app that should offer the user the posibility to take and save pictures within the app. I am quite confused about how this is handled in Android:

```
private void takePicture() {
    File targetDir = new File(somewere in the filesystem...);
    targetDir.mkdirs();
    File targetFile = new File(targetDir, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    Uri targetFilrUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

    pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, targetFilrUri);
    startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, actionID);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { 
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This workes fine and without any problem, if `targetDir` is a public folder, e.g. within `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. As soon as I try to use a folder within the apps internal directory the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity does not work any more. I am still able to take a picture, but the activity does not return to my app any more. The only way to return to my app is to cancel `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

This is not very good problem/error handling but at least the way `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`behalves makes sense: **The `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`"app" cannot access the internal storage of another app (my app) to save the picture there.**

Ok, now I can only save pictures to the `ExternalStorageDirector`. This would be OK (could copy/move them from there manually) but **the problem is, that there is no guarantee, that there even is a `ExternalStorageDirector`**. It could be unmounted, disconnected or simple not there.

So, what is the right way to take a picture?

Is there any public folder that is guaranteed to be available? Something like a public cache dir? So far I could only find information about the internal storage (not public) and the external storage (no guarantees)...